# Efficient Password Hashing Over Multiple Requests

Tags: web-services, security, google-app-engine, rest

I run a REST service on AppEngine (which may not be relevant).  Each REST request is accompanied by a user id and password, and at the beginning of each request I hash the password to see if it matches my records before proceeding.

This is working well, theoretically, but in practice I get bursts of requests from users - 4 or 5 a second.  It's taking BCrypt 500ms to hash the password for each request!  What a waste!

Clearly, I don't want to optimize the BCrypt time down.  Are there standard practices for caching hashes?  Would memcache be a safe place to store a table of recently hashed passwords and their hashes?  I guess at that point I might as well store the users' plain-text passwords in Memcache.  I'd love to do a 3ms memcache lookup instead of a 500ms hash, but security is paramount.  Would it make more sense to implement some sort of session abstraction?

Thanks for any advice!

Edit for extra context: this is a gradebook application that stores sensitive student data (grades).  Teachers and students log in from everywhere, including over wifi, etc. Every successful request is sent over https.

Comment: Wow, wouldn't have expected a google app engine operation as fundamental as that to take so long... issuing a session cookie is fairly standard, but is subject to theft/hijack if not on a secure connection... a bit more context about  your application would probably help ppl give more useful answers - what are your acceptable tolerances... is this a banking application? (doubt it if hosted on google apps, but just a theoretical question...) :)

Comment: @Nathan: part of the issue here is that bcrypt is *supposed* to be slow (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching). But as Rhuidean says, you can use the passphrase to establish a session key, which can be (a) large, (b) random, and (c) short-lived, and therefore is much harder to brute-force, either online by flooding the server with requests or offline if an attacker somehow acquired the stored hash of the session key. So you can use fewer rounds of hash for session keys than you would for a passphrase - for most purposes I reckon you could use zero rounds, and store plain session keys.

Comment: @Nathan: I added the context you were looking for in the OP.  Thanks for the idea about a quicker hash for session keys, @SteveJessop; I think I probably will use zero if I go this route, but I hadn't thought of adjusting the difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet given your current approach is to keep a mapping of attempted passwords to their bcrypted form in memcache. If you're concerned for some reason about storing a plaintext password in memcache, then use an `md5` or `sha1` hash of the attempted password as a key instead.

The extra step isn't really necessary. Item stored in memcache don't leak to other apps.

Comment: I guess the thing to check is, "is sensitive data in memcache any more capable of leaking than sensitive data in the memory of the process that runs my app?". If the answer is "no", which seems fairly likely, then caching the password is no worse than processing it at all. If the answer is "yes" then you'd have to decide whether the difference in risk crosses some threshold you care about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dave! I went ahead and implemented this and see a 500ms reduction in almost every request, which for some requests is like a 95% speedup - and it's transparent to the clients of the API.  I'm excited to see the billing info for today ;)

Answer (score 2):

The usual rule of thumb with REST APIs is to have them remain fully stateless, however, as with *goto* there is a time and a place depending on your requirements. If you're not averse to the idea of having the client store a temporary session key which you only need to regenerate occasionally then you might try that out.

When a client makes a request, check whether they're sending a session key variable along with the user ID and password. If they are not, generate one based on the current server time and their password, then pass it back to the client. Store it in your own database along with its creation time. Then, when a client makes a request that includes a session key, you can verify it by directly comparing it to the session key stored in your database without requiring a hash. As long as you invalidate the key every few hours, it shouldn't be much of a security concern. Then again, if you're currently sending the password and user ID in the clear then you already have security issues.

Comment: "without requiring a hash" - or if you're worried about that, then using a much faster hash than EKSBlowfish.

Comment: I could make the session key optional, I suppose, to preserve the statelessness of the API for clients that want it, but allow clients to use the session to speed things up.  Thanks for the suggestion.  The only thing I don't like is that it would require a special /getsession request, or extra information in a response.  

ps: I send every request over https and have the userid/password cookies marked secure, so they're never sent in the clear

Comment: If you're returning data in the form of XML/JSON or in some other relational  format, I'd recommend including the session key in the response. However you only need to do this on first authentication or once the session key has expired, which is a time period you can control based on your server load.

Comment: Why do you have userid and password stored in cookies in the first place?